# React js refresh functional component after all data fetched

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I am using a react functional component and  i am fetching external data inside for loop.The problem is component refreshing infinitely.below is what i am trying to do-

```
const SongGrid = (props: any) => {
 const [songData, setSongData] = useState(props.location.state.items);
 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = (data: any) => {
     CommonService.postApiExecutor('getdata', {data.id})
     .then((response) => { 
        element.extProp1 = response.data.one;
        setSongData(
        songData.map((item: any) =>
          item.song_id === song.song_id
            ? { ...item, extProp1 : extProp1 }
            : item,
        ),
      );
      })
    }
    songDataObj.forEach((element: any) => {
      fetchData(element)
    })
 },[songData])
 return (
  <div>
   <table>
     <thead><th>Song Name</th><th>Ext property 1</th></thead>
     <tbody>
      {songDataObj.map((song: any, i: any) => (
       <tr>
        <td>song.songName</td>
        <td>{song.extProp1?song.extProp1:''}</td>
       </tr>
      ))}
     </tbody>
   </table>
 </div>
 )
}
```

I am updating songData on each response and the table cells refreshing at least 70 ,80 times and page crashing.

Answer (score 0):

when you only want to do something like `componentDidMount` you need to add this

`useEffect(()=>{
    [you code here]
},[])` `<---- you forgot the brackets`

if there is nothing in the brackets it will only run the code that is inside of useEffect once.

if you a variable is inside of the bracket it will run the useEffect every time the value inside of the bracket changes

Answer (score 0):

use this `useEffect(() => ,[])` instead of `useEffect(() => )`

the problem is that you call setState inside useEffect and every time a re-render occur it cause useEffect to run again and it call setState again and it call useEffect again and it call setState again and ........... it continue for ever. so to limit this you must put [dependency] on the end of your useEffect hook. to control when a useEffect call trigger or you can control it by putting an If clause inside useEffect to not trigger network call again.

Comment: I have tried useEffect(() => ,[]) , but the problem is ,then Component wont refresh when api response comes back. and the table holds old values.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of using `setState` inside `useEffect`.
It will run every time state changes while itself changing the state.
You can define dependency in `useEffect` function to prevent it from infinite re-run.

```
useEffect(()=>{} ,[])
```

Adding empty array as second parameter to `useEffect` means it will only run once when component mounted.